# Facing error - Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize an object then write it into a cache. And plan to read it after de-serializing it. But running into this error -
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.lang.String from Object value (token JsonToken.START_OBJECT) at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]`

The two methods look like below. Fwiw, this is the value written into cache: {"id":"abcdefg"}

```
private void writeInCache (Account account) {
JSONObject bankObject = new JSONObject();
Object object = account.getBank().getId();
bankObject.put("id" ,account.getBank().getId());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] jsonBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(bankObject);
CacheResponse cacheResponse = cacheClient.create(account.getAccountNumber().
                           getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), jsonBytes);}



public readFromCache(){
CacheResponse cacheResponse = cacheClient.get(account.getAccountNumber().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
if(null != cacheResponse.getValue()){
      ByteArrayInputStream byteInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(cacheResponse.getValue());
       bank.setId(mapper.readValue(byteInput, String.class));
.......//rest code
}
```

Comment: Your json is an object, which should not be deserialised to `String.class`. Simple way is to readValue as Map, and that call `get("id")`

Comment: @samabcde Even when I do `mapper.readValue(byteInput, Map.class)`, the resulting map from it doesn't contain any ID

Comment: Not sure which lib you are using for `JSONObject`, but since the byte array is from writing `JSONObject`, you should read it also as `JSONObject`.